# Advance to next Column

Tags: excel, vba

I am using the following code to edit some Data in an Excel File

```
Dim SF1 As Long
Dim EF1 As Long
Dim MaxRows As Long
SF1 = 2
MaxRows = Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row
EF1 = MaxRows

While SF1 <= MaxRows
If Range("D" & SF1) <> "" Then
    Range("A" & EF1).Value = Range("A" & SF1).Value
    Range("B" & EF1).Value = Range("B" & SF1).Value
    Range("C" & EF1).Value = Range("D" & SF1).Value
    SF1 = SF1 + 1
    EF1 = EF1 + 1
Else
    SF1 = SF1 + 1
End If
Wend
End Sub
```

However I would like to increment the column of D to E to...(ideally)ZZ after the MaxRows is reached. Can you provide me any input on this?

I tried something like this:

```
Dim SF1 As Long
Dim EF1 As Long
Dim MaxRows as Long
Column As String
SF1=2
MaxRows = Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row
EF1 = MaxRows
Col = "D"

While Col <>"ZZ"
    While SF1 <= MaxRows
        If Range("D" & SF1) <> "" Then
            Range("A" & EF1).Value = Range("A" & SF1).Value
            Range("B" & EF1).Value = Range("B" & SF1).Value
            Range("C" & EF1).Value = Range("D" & SF1).Value
            SF1 = SF1 + 1
            EF1 = EF1 + 1
        Else
            SF1 = SF1 + 1
        End If
    Wend
    Col = Col+1
Wend
End Sub
```

which doesn't work as this is not compatible (string and +1 as this is something for a number). So how can I advance the Column here especially taking into account that after Z AA follows in Excels column names.

Thanks for your help and Best regards!

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution Code now looks as follows:

```
Dim SF1 As Long
Dim EF1 As Long
Dim MaxRows As Long
Dim ColNumber As Long
Dim ColLetter As String
Dim FinalColLetter As String
FinalColLetter = "BB"
ColNumber = 4
SF1 = 2
MaxRows = Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row
EF1 = MaxRows + 1

While ColNumber <= Range(FinalColLetter & 1).Column
    ColLetter = Split(Cells(1, ColNumber).Address, "$")(1)
        While SF1 <= MaxRows
            If Range(ColLetter & SF1) <> "" Then
                Range("A" & EF1).Value = Range("A" & SF1).Value
                Range("B" & EF1).Value = Range("B" & SF1).Value
                Range("C" & EF1).Value = Range(ColLetter & SF1).Value
                SF1 = SF1 + 1
                EF1 = EF1 + 1
            Else
                SF1 = SF1 + 1
        End If
        Wend
        SF1 = 2
    ColNumber = ColNumber + 1
Wend
```

Does what I need